# Jquery input fields sum strange result

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum, concatenation, input-field

I would like to sum these number input to each of which is associated a specific price in a related span 
But with my function I get very wrong results ...
Essentially the total do a concatenate instead of doing a sum, but I have tried every kind of combination of parseFloat and parseInt with always the same error
where am I wrong?

here is html:

```
<table width="300" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <td width="40">1</td>

    <td><input class="txt" type="number" name="txt"/><span    class="valore">10</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>

    <td><input class="txt" type="number" name="txt"/><span class="valore">20</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>

    <td><input class="txt" type="number" name="txt"/><span class="valore">30</span></td>
</tr>
<tr id="summation">

    <td align="right">Sum :</td>
    <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".txt").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            TotalSum();
        });
    });

});

function TotalSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    var prezzo = 0;
    $(".txt").each(function() {
              prezzo = parseFloat($(".valore").text()); 
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum +=(parseFloat(this.value))*(parseFloat(prezzo));
        }

    });
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: `$(".txt").on("change keyup", TotalSum);` is better and shorter

Answer (score 0):

You should assign distinct IDs to the elements instead of the class `valore`. Otherwise, prezzo is always 10, as it's the first element jQuery finds with the class `valore`. Alternatively, you can use the jQuery methods that dynamically select sibling nodes that Chintan suggested.

Secondly, in the future, it could be useful to know the difference between using `$(".valore").text()` and `$(".valore").html()`, if you were to ever change the contents of the `valore` element. The first method only fetches the text within the element and ignores all HTML tags, while the second returns the HTML tags as well.

Comment: No. I would consider both of your reccomendations as worse than the current code. He has only to find the proper valore-node. Like that for example: `$(this).siblings(".valore").text()`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are doing wrong.

You are getting the `span` values using `$('.valore')` selector. There are 3 span elements with `.valore` - so `prezzo = parseFloat($(".valore").text());` will give you the combined concatenated value `"102030"` no matter what.

Try using `$(this).next().text();` or more generally `$(this).siblings(".valore").text());` instead. The following works. Check it out.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".txt").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            TotalSum();
        });
    });

});

function TotalSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    var prezzo = 0;
    $(".txt").each(function() {
        prezzo = parseFloat($(this).siblings(".valore").text()); 
        //console.log(prezzo);
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum +=(parseFloat(this.value))*(parseFloat(prezzo));
        }

    });
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="300" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <td width="40">1</td>

    <td><input class="txt" type="number" name="txt"/><span    class="valore">10</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>

    <td><input class="txt" type="number" name="txt"/><span class="valore">20</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>

    <td><input class="txt" type="number" name="txt"/><span class="valore">30</span></td>
</tr>
<tr id="summation">

    <td align="right">Sum :</td>
    <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$(this).next()` works fine here; when the markup/order changes you might need `$(this).siblings(".valore")`. Just saying, in case he needs it.

Comment: @Thomas I agree. Thanks for pointing it out - edited the answer to reflect it.